# How to prevent creation of mold while sprouting wheatgrass indoors?

Tags: mold, sprouting

I'm sprouting wheat grass indoors and its growing pretty well. I've been following video's that I've seen on YouTube to sprout it.

The problem I have is that I've reached the stage that I remove the lid for the grass to start getting sunlight and I see white fuzz in/around the roots (I've been growing them on a white paper towel and on coconut coir (as an experiment).).

I know that healthy air circulation and managed humidity prevents mold but will adding in that air circulation now help kill off the mold to let the grass continue to grow?

[image: growing on the paper towel]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might, it might not, but there's no point in not removing the lid and exposing it to the air - it's come this far, and it may just be fine. If its not, then you'll have to start again, there isn't anything you can do to get rid of the mould (if that's actually what it is, and not just masses of tiny root hairs) anyway.

Comment: Thanks,  I am hoping its the latter as its been just a few days (2 or 3)

Comment: I can't actually see anything that looks like mould - I'm assuming the white at the bottom is the kitchen paper...

Comment: Get out a magnifying glass and look closer. Is it mold or is it the fine hair roots that develop off the initial root spike?

Comment: I've magnified the pic times 4 -its a good pic to start with, but even so, I still can't see any mould, just looks like further root initiation

Comment: Looks like roots to me too.  And it's nowhere else whereas mold would not be that indiscriminate.  Mold tends to fluff out, whereas I think we are seeing linear roots radiating out from the main root..

Comment: There's a mold that looks a lot like root hairs. I minimize this by using fresh garden soil each time. Wetting it, roughing up the surface, lay down seed, and cover with about an inch of loose, good, potting soil. Takes a week or so for sprouts to get through the soil and green up, but yield is much better than with just laying seeds on surface. Roots that penetrate into the garden soil layer are too well anchored for the cat to pull up.

Answer (score 4):

If it is mold, spraying or drenching with an hydrogen peroxide solution should kill it. Two tablespoons of 3% peroxide in a quart of water. It won't harm your sprouts.

Answer (score 3):

If it is really fungus that you see, and not just root hairs, it could be the symbiosis between the plant and the fungus which is called (arbuscular) [mycorrhiza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhiza).

The plant gets minerals from the fungus, and gives in return sugar back. Wheat and many crops need this symbiosis, so you don't have to remove it, it is part of how wheat grows properly. The association is mutualistic, which means both benefit from the partnership.

However, the fluffy white stuff is probably root hairs, but is not very good visible on the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I had found solution for not let wheatgrass get mold .At first put the wheat grain into water and soak them for 4 hour and prepare a soil and after put the wheat grain direct into soil and you had finished .put some out of water in the soil and you will see wheat grads will grow in between 2 to 4 days.

Comment: I use a 5 hour soak with Potassium nitrate (2g/L 20mM) which gives me better germination rates.

Answer (score 0):

Wheat has a feathery root system. It means that your wheat is growing really fine and good. If you take a seed and see it carefully you see that they are connected. Mould grow randomly like a spider web. If you do think it's mold. Add half or full table spoon of baking soda and spray it until its gone.